# On how many device can install a single user license of Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: license, visual-studio-2012

I have my eye on Visual Studio 2012.  I'm buying it for myself so I only want to pay for one user license.

I have my desktop computer at home, my work laptop, and a tablet.  On how many devices can I install Visual Studio on without Microsoft remotely restricting it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the VS 2012 (and MSDN Subscriptions) licensing document that can be found at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350 you are allowed to install Visual Studio on just about any number of machines where you are the single user of the software. From the license text:

> Where the Software Can be Installed and Run The licensed user can install and use the software on any number of devices. The software can be installed and used on your devices at work, at home, at school, and even on devices at a customer’s office or on dedicated hardware hosted by a 3rd party. However, the software is not licensed for use on 3rd party shared servers (“cloud” environments) or in production environments.

Comment: Now, this is extremely generous from Microsoft!

Comment: [VS 2018](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Visual-Studio-2018-Licensing-Whitepaper-November-2017.pdf) licensing whitepaper says the same: `All Visual Studio subscriptions and Visual Studio Professional are licensed on a per-user basis. Each licensed user may install and use the software on any number of devices to design, develop, test, and demonstrate their programs.  `

Comment: Still the case for VS2019, it seems. All the VS licences are here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/

Comment: And still true för VS 2022 Pro & Enterprise in the "expected" way, i.e. it does not apply if you install on a system you don't maintain yourself like Azure cloud or a customer's computer.

`"One user may install and use copies of the software on your devices to develop and test applications. This includes using copies of the software on your own internal servers that remain fully dedicated to your own use."`