# MSDN Visual Studio - Can I still install on home computer?

Tags: visual-studio, msdn

In the "good old days", I could logon to MSDN from any computer, and download Visual Studio. Not sure if it is like this for everyone, but now, I have to logon only on my corporate laptop.  If I try to logon on my personal computer, it says:

[image]

This client also prohibits USB and external storage devices.  I would like to install Visual Studio on my personal laptop. Is this not allowed in general, or is just because my client has turned on a higher level of security on the logon/verification.

See [https://superuser.com/questions/498069/on-how-many-device-can-install-a-single-user-license-of-visual-studio-2012#:~:text=Where%20the%20Software%20Can%20be,hosted%20by%20a%203rd%20party](https://superuser.com/questions/498069/on-how-many-device-can-install-a-single-user-license-of-visual-studio-2012#:%7E:text=Where%20the%20Software%20Can%20be,hosted%20by%20a%203rd%20party). Amongst other things, it says you can install on any computers

> The software can be installed and used on your devices at work, at
> home, at school, and even on devices at a customer’s office or on
> dedicated hardware hosted by a 3rd party.

I've never had to ask the company before, because I could download from my personal computer.

Comment: Your corporate laptop is managed by your corporation. What you can and can't do is defined by the IT department.

Comment: Right, but I'm asking about my personal laptop.  I'd like to install Visual Studio there; and in the past that was allowed.

Comment: *I have to logon only on my corporate laptop* is what you wrote. Perhaps [edit] the question to clarify?

Comment: The organization that owns the account you are logging into has prohibited the ability to login into the account from outside their domain. This means you won’t be able to access and install the MSDN account with the license to Visual Studio

Comment: What the others have said is correct. If you really want to use Visual Studio on your personal computer, download the Community edition as it is free.

Comment: These are "better new days". You want the Visual Studio Community Edition, which others have noted is free. Don't login with your work account.